# setInterval running really slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I made a website where I need to animate strings that are longer than the containing parent.

This is the website: [Here](http://www.pawpointer.com)

If you click on next, you can see multiple pages of breeders with long names, that need to animate from left to right, but this only happens after 10 or 15 seconds and it takes a long time for it to start.

Now I have checked my code and this is where I create my functions:

```
function newsTicker() {
console.log('newsTicker')
verifyLength();
$('.breeder').not('.short-breed-name').each(function() {
    var breederNameWidth = $(this).find('.breeder_name').width();
    var divBreederNameWidth = $(this).find('.breeder_name_div').width();
    var diff = Math.max(parseInt(breederNameWidth - divBreederNameWidth),0);
    // console.log('diff:',diff)
    $(this).find('.breeder_name').animate({
        marginLeft: -diff
    }, 3000,
    function(){
        $(this).animate({
            marginLeft : 0
        },3000)
    })
})
}

function verifyLength() {
    // console.log('verifyLength')
    $('.breeder.visible').each(function() {
        // debugger
        var breederNameWidth = $(this).find('.breeder_name').width() + 10;
        var divBreederNameWidth = $(this).find('.breeder_name_div').innerWidth();
        if(breederNameWidth < divBreederNameWidth) {
            $(this).addClass('short-breed-name');
            $(this).find('.breeder_name').css({'width':'100%','text-align':'center'})
        }
    })
}
```

And this is where I call newsTicker:

```
function breederAnimate(){
    verifyLength();
    newsTicker();
    setInterval(newsTicker, 1000);
}
```

Why is it so slow when my times are between 1 and 3 seconds?

Comment: "BITDEFENDER has blocked this page"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling `setTimeout` not `setInterval` because you only want your animation to run once. You're restarting your animations every second

Also, you should be cancelling existing setIntervals when you click next or previous

Comment: Nope, I want it to run multiple times, once every couple of seconds.

Comment: Then why is your `setInterval` set to every second? And each animation takes 3 seconds? Maybe your `setInterval` should be set to 3000 and your animate calls set to 1000. Also, you need to make sure you cancel your setInterval when you click next again

Comment: Yes, I think that was my mistake. I was calling the function that was setting the interval for every click on the next or previous, thus increasing the time enormously.